# Rails, Giving a remote partial local variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, partial

So I have this partial that has 2 variables: `coursetitle` and `routenumber`. I tried setting these variables from the view but I can't access these from the partial unless I make them global. I am looking for a way to pass on these variables from either the view or the controller but I am a bit lost as to why I can't set them from the view.

```
<div>
<h2> Correct!</h2>       

      <%= link_to "Next", "/courses/#{coursetitle}_q#{routenumber}",class:"btn btn-warning" %>
      <%= render 'layouts/coursefooter' %>


      <!-- fix for bootstrap navbar render bug -->
      <script> 
      $( ".puller" ).addClass( "pull-left" );
      </script>
```

I call this partial by :remote like this:

```
<%= link_to "Correct", correct_answer_courses_path,:remote => true,:class=>"btn btn-warning"  %>
```

And my correct_answer.js looks like this:

```
$("#correct_answer").html("<%= j render partial: "beginnercourse/correct" %>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller, you can define instance variables `@coursetitle` and `@routenumber`

```
$("#correct_answer").html("<%= j render partial: "beginnercourse/correct", coursetitle: @coursetitle, routenumber: @routenumber %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear as to your setup. If `correct_answer.js` is rendered at the same time as your view, you can make `coursetitle` and `routenumber` instance variables and set them in the controller (`@coursetitle` and `@routenumber`). Then you'll be able to access them in both the view and partial.

You could also look into using the [cells gem](https://github.com/apotonick/cells), which I believe was created to handle problems like this. I don't know if there's a baked in way to pass a local variable into a partial in Rails.

But it sounds like `correct_answers.js` is not rendered at the same time as your view. In which case you can make sure that the `correct_answer_courses_path` route includes the values for `coursetitle` and `routenumber`. e.g. in your routes.rb file

```
get '/course/:title/route/:number', to: 'controller#action', as: 'correct_answer_courses'
```

and you'd get the path with `correct_answer_courses_path(coursetitle, routenumber)`. and then in the controller action that renders the partial get those values with `params[:title]` and `params[:number]`, set them to instance variable there, and then make use of them in the partial.